# How to terminate a character pointer at a certain location in c?

Tags: c, string, pointers, null, char

I'm trying to terminate a character pointer in c, at a specific location by setting the null terminator to it.

for examples if I have a char pointer

```
 char *hi="hello";
```

I want it to be `"hell"` by setting the `o` to null.

I have tried doing this with strcpy with something like

```
strcpy(hi+4, "\0");
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Some clearification: You cant terminate a pointer. The pointer will point to an array of characters (sometimes called a "string") and you may modify this array. if one of there chars is 0 it is interpreted as EndOfString in `C`. So you may just set one of the array elements to 0 == '\0`== 0x0 (but not null, which is a **pointer** with value 0x00000000)

Comment: Please don't edit question in a way that makes the existing answers look out-of-context or wrong altogether. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 7):

`"hello"` is a string literal so it cannot modified, and in your code, `hi` points to the first element in such a literal. Any attempt to modify the thing it points to is *undefined behaviour*.

However, if you create your own `char` array, you can insert a null terminator at will. For example,

```
char hi[] = "hello"; // hi is array with {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
hi[4] = '\0';
```

Here, `hi` is a length 6 array of `char` which you own and whose contents you can modify. After setting the 5th element, it contains `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\0', '\0'}`, and printing it would yield `hell`.

Answer (score 4):

**Point 1:**

In your code

```
char *hi="hello";
```

`hi` is a pointer to a *string literal*. It may not be modifiable. You've to use a `char` array instead and *initialize* that with the same string literal. Then you can modify the contenets of that array as you may want.

**Point 2:**

You don't need `strcpy()` to copy a single `char`. You can simply assign the value using the assignment operator `=`.

Note: You don't terminate a *pointer*, you terminate a`char` array with a null-terminator to make that a *string*.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is a literal you can't modify it. Otherwise:

To terminate a C string after 4 characters you could use:

```
*(he+4) = 0;
```

or

```
he[4] = 0;
he[4] = '\0';
```

or, since `strcpy()` copies all the characters specified and then appends a '\0' character:

```
strcpy(he+4, "");
```

but this is rather *obfuscated*.

Comment: Not if the string is a literal.

Comment: True, I modified my answer